# Awaiting a Promise result within an Angular RxJS Observable Method

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, rxjs, observable

The method below is expected to be an Observable that needs some data from a promise function to continue execution.

```js
    async function observableFunc(): Observable<string> {
      const response = await promiseFunc()
      return anotherObservableFunc(response)
    }
```

This throws an error because async functions are supposed to return a promise.

I tried to use `.toPromise()` but then I can’t do something using `.pipe()` later on like this:

```
observableFunc().pipe(...)
```

What's a dev posed to do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`from`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/from), which converts a `Promise` (among other things) to an `Observable`:

```
function observableFunc(): Observable<string> {
  return from(promiseFunc()).pipe(
    concatMap(() => anotherObservableFunc())
  );
}
```

I'm using `concatMap`, because it's more descriptive. It basically says, wait until the previous `Observable` completes (which a Promise does) and then subscribe to the other `Observable`.

Although in this case, there would be no difference in using `mergeMap` or `switchMap`. Semantically, the `concatMap` is a better fit

Answer (score 2):

You have to convert the promise to an observable

```
function observableFunc(): Observable<string> {
  return from(promiseFunc())
   .pipe(
      swithMapTo(anotherObservableFunc())
    );

}
```

I am assuming anotherObservableFunc returns an observable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
promiseFunc(){
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        resolve('start of new Promise');
      });
  }
```

create a new promise in this way

you can also wait for few seconds to try like this

```
promiseFunc(){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve("done!"), 1000)
  });
}
```

and its call will be like

```
async function observableFunc(){
      const response = await promiseFunc()
      // no do whatever you like as next statement will be executed after response gets it value

    }
```

Comment: The question about defining the promiseFunc method, it about how to actually await its response within the observable method